# How to make to lint BEM-style using stylelint and stylelint-selector-bem-pattern?

Tags: css, lint, postcss, stylelint

I'm trying to lint BEM-style using [stylelint](http://www.stylelint.io) and [`stylelint-selector-bem-pattern` plugin](https://github.com/davidtheclark/stylelint-selector-bem-pattern) but can't get it work.

My config is the following:

- node: 5.11.0
- gulp-stylelint: ^2.0.2
- stylelint-selector-bem-pattern: ^0.2.3

`.stylelintrc`

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "stylelint-selector-bem-pattern"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "selector-bem-pattern": {
            preset: "suit"
        },
    },
    "extends": "@alienlebarge/stylelint-config",
}
```

And a CSS files for tests

```
.12ad2-asd--sad {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}






#yeah {
    height: 10px;
}
```

I get the error message from [`@alienlebarge/stylelint-config`](https://github.com/alienlebarge/stylelint-config) but not from [`stylelint-selector-bem-pattern` plugin](https://github.com/davidtheclark/stylelint-selector-bem-pattern)

```
src/assets/foehn/styles/foehn.css
 4:1  ✖  Unexpected empty line    max-empty-lines
 5:1  ✖  Unexpected empty line    max-empty-lines
 6:1  ✖  Unexpected empty line    max-empty-lines
 7:1  ✖  Unexpected empty line    max-empty-lines
 8:1  ✖  Unexpected empty line    max-empty-lines
 9:1  ✖  Unexpected empty line    max-empty-lines
 9:1  ✖  Unexpected id selector   selector-no-id
```

Comment: In `.stylelintrc`, you should probably preset to 'bem':
[`'plugin/selector-bem-pattern': {'preset': 'bem'}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342416).
It's very strange that
['suit' is the default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-bem-linter#preset-patterns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code here it looks like the problem probably is that you did not define your component at the top of the CSS file: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter#defining-a-component

Comment: It's often overlooked (even by me).

Comment: @davidtheclark did you manage to solve this? I'm looking to implement a gulp task. Would be helpful if you could publish here a working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Stylelint plugin will only run over defined components, which in the example is not the case.

As defined at the [project documentation](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter#defining-a-component-and-utilities):

> The plugin will only lint the CSS if it knows the context of the CSS: is it a utility or a
>   component. To define the context, use the configuration options to define it based on the filename
>   (`css/components/*.css`) or use a special comment to define context for the CSS after it.
>   When defining a component, the component name is needed.

You can either define implicitly at the `stylelintrc.json`:

```
...,
implicitComponents: 'components/**/*.css',
...
```

Or at which component with a comment into `MyComponent.css`:

```
/** @define ComponentName */

.MyComponent {...}
```