# Invalid component selector with Selector Bem Pattern

Tags: stylelint

I get an issue with the plugin `stylelint-selector-bem-pattern` of Stylelint.

**My Stylelint rules :**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "stylelint-selector-bem-pattern"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "selector-class-pattern": null,
    "color-function-notation": "legacy",
    "alpha-value-notation": "number",
    "plugin/selector-bem-pattern": {
      "preset": "bem",
      "componentName": "[A-Z]+",
      "componentSelectors": {
        "initial": "^\\.{componentName}(?:-[a-z]+)?$",
        "combined": "^\\.combined-{componentName}-[a-z]+$"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My SCSS component :**

```
// @define TOTO

.toto_test {
  color: red;
}

.toto__test {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Stylelint errors :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the `suit` preset, whose [naming conventions](https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/naming-conventions.md) are:

- `ComponentName`
- `ComponentName--modifierName`
- `ComponentName-descendentName`
- `ComponentName.is-stateOfComponent`

If you wish to follow the SuitCSS naming conventions you should write:

```
/* @define Button */

.Button-loader {}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`preset`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter#preset-patterns) option to specify the [`bem` naming conventions](https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#naming-rules):

```
"plugin/selector-bem-pattern": {
  "preset": "bem"
}
```

You should remove the `componentName` and `componentSelectors` properties as they overwrite the `"bem"` `preset` with custom patterns.

This will allow:

```
/* @define button */

.button__loader {}
```

Comment: I tried to use the preset "bem". But it is not working. You can see the edit in my post.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it clearer that you need to remove the `componentName` and `componentSelectors` properties as they overwrite the preset.

Comment: If I only keep the preset `bem`. The class name `.toto_test` passed and I don't have anny error message...